# storing returned value from google geocoding in an external javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, return

Unable to **store the returned value from google geocoding** into a global/external (javascript) variable (*latlng1*, in the following case).... perhaps because the the variable gets its value before the geocoding could complete...

For in the code below:

```
alert(('latlon='+latlng1); //shows undefined
```

But,

```
alert('got value = '+latLng);   //gives the coorect value
```

So, how to wait for geocoding to return a non-null value before assigning it to the variable??

And would this solve the problem? Or are there other flaws in the code too??

besides this however all parts of the code work fine (as mentioned through comments in code below) ; I see the marker also being placed correctly on the map;

Here is my code:-

```
    <script src="path_to_javascript_file.js"></script>

    $(some_element).click(function() {

             var input = document.getElementById(some_input_element).vlaue ;

             var get_geocodes =   function get_value(latLng) {
                              alert('got value = '+latLng);   //gives the coorect value
                              if (latLng == null){
                                  geocode(input, get_geocodes)} 
                              return latLng;
                                     }

             latlng1 =  geocode(input, get_geocodes);
             alert('latlon='+latlng1);  //says undefined
```

And following is my javascript_file.js (that is included at the beginning of the above code) :

```
function geocode(query, mycallback) { 

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            latLng = null
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': query}, 
            function callback(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
                  var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
                  console.log('geocoding successful : ' + latLng);   //gives the correct value
                  add_marker(latLng, query);                 
                  mycallback(latLng);                    
                }

             else {
                  console.log("geocoding unsuccessful because of: " + status);
                }
            });  
          }


function add_marker(latLng , query) {

                    var new_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(latLng.lat(), latLng.lng()),
                      map: map,
                      title: query ,
                      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP                
                      }); 

                    console.log(new_marker.getPosition().lat());  //gives the correct value
                    console.log(mew_marker.getPosition().lng());  //gives the correct value
                    alert('added_marker'+latLng+',,'+location);   //gives the correct value

}
```

Comment: Geocoding is asynchronous.  If you need to "wait" for the value to be available, you do that by handling it in the callback function.

Comment: sorry, that was a typing mistake I did here that I have corrected now...its `.value` in the original code...

Comment: @geocodezip what more do I need to add to mycallback function (mentioned in the code) ?? the link you provided isn't helping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you need to wait until *google.maps.Geocoder()* finishes its execution.

Your function *geocode* doesn't return anything, so no suprises that variable *latlng1* is undefined. Anyway if *geocode* would return *latLng* value you have no guarantee that *latlng1* will be defined.

My suggestion:

1. Just call *geocoder* function without assigning it to *latlng1*.
2. Make *latlng1* variable global by initialising it outside all functions.
3. Don't use *latLng* variable at all and just assign the required value directly to the global variable *latlng1* like this:

   ```
   latlng1 = results[0].geometry.location;
   ```
4. Replace *latLng* variable with *latlng1* in these two calls: add_marker(latlng1, query) and *mycallback(latlng1)* functions or (This last advice is not essential, just recommended.) just redefine add_marker() to accept only one value - *query* and *mycallback()* accept no values and just use global *latlng1* inside those functions.

Comment: but isn't the `get_value()` function (stored in `var get_geocodes` and passed as `mycallback` to the `geocode()` function ), `return` the `latLng` value, as it is being called here : `if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length): mycallback(latLng); `?

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. You need to add return statement specifically for geocode() function. Only then goecode() will return some value.

Comment: also can't assign it directly to a global variable...because I need to store multiple values in different variables based on the incoming requests...

Comment: okay..can something like this done -- `a_function(args) { return b_function(args);}` ,,where the  b_function is --  `b_function(args) { return some_value;}` ,,such that a `var result = a_function(arg1);` gets the `returned value` from `b_function`?

Comment: Just add _return latlng;_ right before the last curly bracket in function geocode. That' should do what you want, but I really doubt this is a best way. Could you explain what actually are you trying to do? I am pretty sure there must be easier way.

Comment: no that doesn't work...had tried this in the very beginning before trying to look for other ways...checked it again however, it `returns null`...as it doesn't wait for the geocoding to complete..

Comment: Oh yes - right! I forgot it myself. So just assign results[0].geometry_location value directly into latlng1 as I explained in my original answer. When you will need latlng1 updated with another value just call geocode() function again.

Or explain what actually you are trying to do.

Comment: solved! ...assigned the value directly; but to a javascript object declared globally....and modified the `geocode(query)` function to include an additional argument `geocode(query, key)` to let the function know which key's value in the object it needs to modify (store results)... thank you for discussing :)

Comment: Congratulations! Accept my answer and let people know that you solved your problem.