# callback function for Google Geocode API returning NULL Value

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the geoCode function that uses a callback function to do something after the asynchronous request has completed. However, it returns a NULL value.

```
 function codeAddress(callback) {

    /***** build string address from form data
    var address = addressOne + "," + addressTwo + "," + region + "," + zip + "," + country;
    *****/

    var geocodeAddress = geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function (results, status) { callback( results ) } );

}

codeAddress(function(returnData){
    console.log("results= " + returnData);
    console.log(returnData);
     });
```

this gives empty array

Comment: have you checked the status..? what status u got ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks status is returning ZERO_RESULTS so obviously returnData would be empty. Many thanks

Comment: Suggested solution in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18283942) might not directly solve your problem but this explains how the Google Geocode API `callback()` works and what causes the `callback()` function to return a null value. Hope the explanation helps you address the encountered error.

Answer (score 0):

```
var returnData = function () {
         return data;
};

codeAddress (returnData ());
```

Should be able to pass what you like.